# Python with SQLAlchemy enconding error

Tags: python, mysql, encoding, character-encoding, sqlalchemy

I have encountered an error while trying to automap tables from a MySQL databases.
The error is :

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe9' in position 7: ordinal not in range(128)
```

This error occurs when I am making a :

```
Base.prepare(engine, reflect=True)
```

My database is in utf8_bin.

Here is my engine connection to the database :

```
engine = create_engine("mysql://User:passwd@127.0.0.1:3308/db?charset=utf8", encoding="utf-8", echo=True)
```

And here is the complete stack trace of the error :

```
 2016-05-12 15:57:39,497 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'sql_mode'
 2016-05-12 15:57:39,497 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ()
 2016-05-12 15:57:39,511 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine SELECT DATABASE()
 2016-05-12 15:57:39,511 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ()
 2016-05-12 15:57:39,537 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine show collation where `Charset` = 'utf8' and `Collation` = 'utf8_bin'
 2016-05-12 15:57:39,538 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ()
 2016-05-12 15:57:39,552 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine SELECT CAST('test plain returns' AS CHAR(60)) AS anon_1
 2016-05-12 15:57:39,552 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ()
 2016-05-12 15:57:39,566 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine SELECT CAST('test unicode returns' AS CHAR(60)) AS anon_1
 2016-05-12 15:57:39,566 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ()
 2016-05-12 15:57:39,580 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine SELECT CAST('test collated returns' AS CHAR CHARACTER SET utf8) COLLATE utf8_bin AS anon_1
 2016-05-12 15:57:39,580 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ()
 2016-05-12 15:57:39,620 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine SHOW FULL TABLES FROM `GesCo`
 2016-05-12 15:57:39,620 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ()
 2016-05-12 15:57:39,652 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine SHOW CREATE TABLE `Client`
 2016-05-12 15:57:39,652 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ()
 2016-05-12 15:57:39,670 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine SHOW CREATE      TABLE `ClientContact`
 2016-05-12 15:57:39,670 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ()
 2016-05-12 15:57:39,686 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine SHOW CREATE TABLE `Dossier`
 2016-05-12 15:57:39,686 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ()
 2016-05-12 15:57:39,705 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine SHOW CREATE TABLE `RDV`
 2016-05-12 15:57:39,705 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ()
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "./api.py", line 29, in <module>
          Base.prepare(engine, reflect=True)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/ext/automap.py", line 788, in prepare
     map_config.map()
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/ext/declarative/base.py", line 592, in map
     return super(_DeferredMapperConfig, self).map()
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/ext/declarative/base.py", line 529, in map
     **self.mapper_args
   File "<string>", line 2, in mapper
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/mapper.py", line 627, in __init__
     self._configure_properties()
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/mapper.py", line 1318, in _configure_properties
     setparent=True)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/mapper.py", line 1607, in _configure_property
     prop.instrument_class(self)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/properties.py", line 182, in instrument_class
     doc=self.doc
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/attributes.py", line 1489, in register_descriptor
     manager.instrument_attribute(key, descriptor)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/instrumentation.py", line 215, in instrument_attribute
     self.install_descriptor(key, inst)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/instrumentation.py", line 269, in install_descriptor
     setattr(self.class_, key, inst)
 UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe9' in position 7: ordinal not in range(128)`
```

Thanks in advance for any help you can give me

EDIT:

Changed all charset variables and the collations variables in mysql, and it stills produces the same error :

```
mysql> show variables like 'collation%';
+----------------------+-----------------+
| Variable_name        | Value           |
+----------------------+-----------------+
| collation_connection | utf8_general_ci |
| collation_database   | utf8_general_ci |
| collation_server     | utf8_general_ci |
+----------------------+-----------------+

mysql> show variables like 'character\_set\_%';
+--------------------------+--------+
| Variable_name            | Value  |
+--------------------------+--------+
| character_set_client     | utf8   |
| character_set_connection | utf8   |
| character_set_database   | utf8   |
| character_set_filesystem | binary |
| character_set_results    | utf8   |
| character_set_server     | utf8   |
| character_set_system     | utf8   |
+--------------------------+--------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have a column name that has a `é` in it, and SQLAlchemy is trying to use that as the attribute name of your model class, but Python 2 only allows ASCII attribute names.

You'll need to [explicitly define this particular class](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/automap.html#specifying-classes-explicitly) with the changed name:

```
Base = automap_base()

class RDV(Base):
    __tablename__ = "RDV"

    ...
    accepted = Column("accepté", Boolean, ...)
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try setting MySQL variables like `character_set_client` to `utf-8`? You might want to run the following query in MySQL and set all values to `utf-8`:

`mysql> show variables like 'character\_set\_%';`

You can also try setting some of the utf-8 collations like `utf8_general_ci` to variables in output of:

`mysql> show variables like 'collation%';`

Comment: Edited the question, still no changes